# Read the contents of a directory using a variable input as a wild card

Tags: python

I have a server that collects 3 CSV files every hour files thus generating 72 files in 24 hours. The files have a date and an hour extension, the hour extensions will be the same every day (for that hour) just the date will change in which they all go into a directory called completed.
Occasionally some files dont get collected in the hour thus i want to find out  which CSV files are missing for that date .

To begin with i want to search for the files in the completed directory that were collected,  using glob function

```
  import sys
  import glob

  csv_files = glob.glob('*.csv')
  print(csv_files)
```

Question : is it possible to make the wild card an input variable, for 
   example if i could input a date into this wild card i could see what files 
   have been generated for that day only , from here i could compare the 72 
   files that should be in the directory (based on the hour).
   Any other ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: The argument to `glob.glob()` is just a string, you can construct it from anywhere.

Comment: I don't understand what's preventing you from using a variable in place of that string. Are you asking us how to take user input? Are you asking us how variables work? What's the problem you're facing?

Comment: If each file is generated at the same time, consistently, then you can create a list of dates and check that each one appears in the directory

Comment: The problem i am facing is how to take the * (wild card) and make it a user input

Comment: `csv_files = glob.glob(input()+'.csv')` Problem solved?

Comment: Yes - that is the solution - Thank you !